# Is it more memory intensive to repeatedly add a class to a dom element in javascript, or to check to see if it exists before adding?

Tags: javascript

I'm running a request animation frame loop that ultimately is running some logic to determine if a class should be added to a dom object. This is running many times a second so I'm interested to make it as performant as possible. Is it better to run :

```
if(something == true) 
  element.classList.add('myClass')
```

or is it less memory intensive to qualify first:

```
if(something == true && !element.classList.contains('myClass'))
  element.classList.add('myClass')
```

I'd like to get an understanding of what happens during the classList.add function. Is that checking for the presence of the class already? Or is each firing of the method updating the dom object, regardless?

Comment: In this case, `Element.classList.toggle` is what you need, as for memory expansiveness, having 1 boolean is minimal, checking it is very inexpensive, so up to you.

Comment: This code is simplified just for a memory comparison, the logic in reality is more complex and doesn't quite fit with a toggle method.

Comment: This is micro-optimizations, they are never worth it unless it is your actual measured bottleneck. If you have the boolean use it, if not use the `contains` method.

Comment: @MichaelWatson, can you post some example of the HTML and the conditions used your javascript? that would help understand your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the if statement with just one method call [classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), here is a snippet:

```js
const div = document.getElementById('elm');
document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
  div.classList.toggle('elm');
});
```

```css
.normal {
 width: 100px;
 height:100px;
 background: red;
 color:#fff;
}

.elm {
 background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="elm" class="normal">This is test div</div>
<button id="toggle">Toggle Class</button>
```

**Update**: for the updated question, for sure if you use `.contains()` it will be more work to do, since classList is a collection/Set, `.contains()` will do searching string matching, not sure about the exact implementation of the searching algorithm for browsers but you can do some profiling using [devtool in chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance) and compare yourself.

Comment: Thanks - I have just updated my question to better explain the question. The toggle isn't the question at heart, it's more whether a .contains is more memory intensive than simple repetitive .add.

Comment: @MichaelWatson, for the updated question, for sure if you use `.contains()` it will be more work to do, since `classList` is  a collection/Set, `.contains()` will do searching string  matching, not sure about the exact implementation of the browsers but you can do some [profiling using devtool in chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance) and compare yourself.

Comment: This sounds like a great answer, if you wanted to put as an answer I can confirm

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably to just use `toggle` with use of the force flag.

```
element.classList.toggle('class', something);
```

This will add `class` to the element only if `something` is true, and vice versa.

---

As to the memory usage, I wouldn't worry too much. The JS engines are pretty well optimized.

Comment: Thanks - I have just updated my question to better explain the question. The toggle isn't the question at heart, it's more whether a .contains is more memory intensive than simple repetitive .add.

Comment: is this applicable if we want to`add` or  `remove` or only for toggle ?

Comment: @Michael Watson, I'd have to agree with Akxe's comment on that. This would be a micro-optimization, which is rarely worth it.

Comment: @SandeshSapkota, this is something specific to the `toggle` method, which makes it behave as a simultaneous `add` and `remove` based on a boolean condition. `add` and `remove` do not have a force flag, but you can always check the documentation on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList